# Global inbox site icon for hot questions

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Basically like the `all sites` and `inbox` tabs, I'd like the `hot questions` tab to have an icon representing the site the questions belong to

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that the tab/UI element this post is talking about no longer exists in that form? (HNQs are now listed in the sidebar on the right, and they do have site icons there.)

Comment: @V2Blast Correct. Hot network questions used to be a tab in the Stack Exchange dropdown of the top bar (see screenshot in the answer here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree, this would be very useful.

You could try the following userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           So Hot Images
// @namespace      http://josh.gitlin.name/javascripts  
// @description    Adds favicon images to the hot questions supercollider
// @version        1.0.2
// @include        http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "(" + grease.toString() + ")()";
document.body.appendChild(script);

function grease()
{
  var hotIcons = function ()
  {
    $('#seContainerHot div.itemBox').each(function(){
      if(!$('img.favicon',this).length)
      {
        var favicon=$('a.siteLink',this)[0].href+'favicon.ico';
        this.innerHTML = '<img class="favicon" src="'+favicon+'" style="float:left;">'+this.innerHTML
      }
    });
  };
  window.setInterval(hotIcons, 1000);
}
```

[Link to install into Greasemonkey or Chrome](http://josh.gitlin.name/javascripts/so_hot_icons.user.js) tested on Chrome 15.0.874.106.

[image: favicon fhc ftw!]

*Yes, I know this script could be improved. It probably doesn't have to run every second <strike>and the icons are on the wrong side</strike>. It was a super quick hack.* But with a bit of motivation I could probably improve it... (hint, hint)